# Heroku Rails app. How to display output of a shell command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, heroku

I would like to be able to display the results of a dig on a url in a view on my application. Is this possible? If so, what would be a good way to do it?

I tried this locally, but it kills the server.

```
<p>
  <%= exec('dig pool.live-322-a.mgaphn.com') %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backticks. For example:

```
<p>
  <%=`dig example.com`%>
</p>
```